# How to get content on timeout in puppeteer (headless chrome)?

Tags: puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

We are using puppeteer to run automated tests on hundreds of websites and URLs. Some of those websites are very slow and run into a timeout. That is often the case because there is an ad that does not finish loading. So increasing the timeout is not an option.

Is there a way to get the currently rendered HTML (DOM) at the moment the timeout is happening? `page.content()` is only returning a promise that is still pending.

Comment: I faced the same problem also. The page I am scrapping does not finish the loading, so page.evaluate does not execute. I hoped for `.waitForSelector`, but it does not work as well.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use something like `evaluate`, which injects a custom JavaScript function to execute. However, if the thread is truly "locked" then it'll likely run into the same issue.

```
const body = await page.evaluate(() => document.documentElement.outerHTML);
```

You might also need to be a little more flexible on how you orchestrate the script by catching `goto` timeouts and then trying the above.

Comment: please don't "spam" with your product in several answers.